# Formal charge in a co-ordinate covalent bond

Tags: coordination-compounds

In coordinate bond, Does the donor atom have positive formal charge and the acceptor atom have negative formal charge?

For example, in carbon monoxide the oxygen atom donates its lone pair of electrons and has positive formal charge and the carbon atom accepts this lone pair and has negative formal charge. The same thing happens in $\ce{NH3BF3}$, the nitrogen atom donates its lone pair of electrons and has positive formal charge and the boron atom accepts this lone pair and has negative formal charge.

Do the molecules which have coordinate bond follow the octet rule?

Answer (score 0):

> In coordinate bond, Does the donor atom have positive formal charge and the acceptor atom have negative formal charge?

Not always. e.g. In a reaction $\ce{NH3 + H+ -> NH4+}$, the lone pair of nitrogen is donated to the proton. As a result, the nitrogen has a positive formal charge, but the formal charge of the hydrogen is $\pm0$.

> Do the molecules which have coordinate bond follow the octet rule?

Not always. e.g. It is difficult to determine whether metal atoms are following octet rules in metal complexes.